# Limit the number of checks that can be done to a set of checkboxes base of the value of a checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

How can I limit the number of checks that can be done to a set of checkboxes based of the value of a checked radio button.

Say I have 3 options radio buttons.

```
Option 1 with value of 1 
Option 2 with value of 2
Option 3 with value of 3
```

Then I have 3 checkboxes.

```
Checkbox 1
Checkbox 2
Checkbox 3
```

By default checkbox is disabled without any radio buttons checked.
If I check Option 1 Radio button - All checkboxes is enabled and I must and only choose 1 out of the 3
If I check option 2 Radio Button - All checkboxes is enabled and I must and only choose 2 out of the 3 
If I check Option 3 Radio Button - All checkboxes is enabled and I must choose all the checkbox.

I have something i started using JSFiddle but i'm not so good with Javascript and needed some help..

**Update:** http://jsfiddle.net/wF38X/

```
<div id="radioButtons">
    <input type="radio" name="quantity" id="radio1">
    <input type="radio" name="quantity" id="radio2">
    <input type="radio" name="quantity" id="radio3">
</div><!-- radioButtons -->
<hr />
<div id="checkBoxes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="color">
    <input type="checkbox" name="color">
    <input type="checkbox" name="color">
</div><!-- checkBoxes -->​
```

Comment: I don't see *any* JavaScript.  What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "I must choose all the checkboxes"? Does the user have to check them all?

Comment: You could at least put values on the input elements for us...

Comment: Theres no javascript in that jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need. Instead of using radio value I just use the index of the radio to determine which checkboxes need to be disabled and unchecked.

```
var $radios = $('#radioButtons input:radio');
var $checks = $('#checkBoxes input:checkbox').prop('disabled', true);

$radios.change(function() {
    var idx = $radios.index(this);
    $checks.prop('disabled', function(index) {
        return index > idx;
    }).filter(':gt('+idx+')').prop('checked',false);

});

/* validate all non disabled checkboxes are checked*/
$('button').click(function() {
    var missingChecks = $checks.filter(function() {
        return !this.checked && !$(this).prop('disabled');
    }).length;

    if (missingChecks) {
        alert('Not all checkboxes selected')
    }    
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/C6SpM/18/

Comment: Oops sorry pasted an old jsfiddle Here it is except instead of disabling a particular checkbox. I want to limit the number of checkbox the user can click. http://jsfiddle.net/wF38X/ not disabling a particular checkbox. User is free to check any of the checkbox.

Comment: why are checkboxes going to be disabled then on page load?

Comment: I guess the check box doesn't really have to be disabled on load and Yes jsfiddle.net/C6SpM/20 is like what I want. I think this will work. Although what I had in mind was a grayed out checkbox instead of being able to check and receiving an error.

Comment: This is something I found http://jsfiddle.net/jaredhoyt/Ghtbu/1/ similar to what I had in mind. But the value > 4 should come from the radio-box.

Comment: is not hard to disable 3rd checkbox if 2 are allowed and once user clicks second one. If they uncheck a box, reanable them all again

Comment: OK  try this   http://jsfiddle.net/C6SpM/21/  The validate button doesn't do anything, just the radios

Comment: Thanks Almost there! except during if I toggle between radio box it doesn't clear out the checkbox...

Comment: just add `$radios.change(function(){$checks.prop('checked',false);})`. A disabled checkbox won't be submitted in a form also

Comment: Sorry but where do I add that to?

Comment: I added it to the end of the javascript code but nothing happened